# Из Топок или из Топков?

Tags: падежи, названия

В Кемеровской области есть город Топки. Как корректно поставить название этого города в родительный падеж?

Comment: Если допустить происхождение названия этого пункта от слова "топь", то, как мне кажется, корректнее будет из Топок. Но насколько это верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что **Топок**, хотя и кажется непривычным.
Но аборигены на меня скорее всего не обидятся.
***Расчет пути от Кемерово до Топок***
https://www.avtodispetcher.ru/distance/path?from=%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE&to=%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8

Строго говоря, такие вещи не могут быть установлены с абсолютной точностью, ибо нет абсолютных правил, только закономерности. При этом даже в кодифицирующих источниках (специальных топонимических словарях) зачастую за основу берется местная традиция.

Но в нашем случае есть соображение, позволяющее отдать предпочтение варианту склонения по женскому образцу. Район - *Топкинский* (то есть уже официальная кодификация), жители - *топкинцы*... "Ин" здесь достаточно характерный признак женского рода. От названия "Топок" (им. п.) было бы "*топковский*", "*топковцы*"...

Answer (score 2):

Первоначальный ответ неверный, см. **Update** ниже.

[Топки - Википедия](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi8-6TBs8vjAhUxQUEAHX2BAIwQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25A2%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BF%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B8&usg=AOvVaw2pLv-xFAYAk1c5vrHZTYmr) утверждает, что ударение падает на "и", Топк**и**.

По аналогии с Лужки, Теремки и т.п. логично говорить "из Топк**о**в".

Гугл-запрос по `"из топков" топки кемерово` эту теорию подтверждает:

```
Классы трансферов из Топков, Кемеровская область в аэропорт Новосибирска
Автобусы из Топков, Кемеровская область

и т.д
```

**Update**: @behemothus прав: "из Топ**о**к".

[ЖЖ местного жителя](https://vas-pop.livejournal.com/358562.html), где он говорит:

```
Столичные радио всегда коверкают его имя, делая ударение на первом слоге. 
И склоняют неправильно, говоря из ТопкОв. А надо – из ТопОк.
Имя города хорошо рифмуется с моей фамилией: Попок из Топок.
```

...

Comment: Тут жк не ударением определяется, а грамматическим родом. Лужок и Теремок - они м.р. И от них  - лужковский, теремковский и проч. А у нас - топкинский.